# TFS vs SharePoint: what is the best location to store documentation?

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, documentation, project-management

Usually, business people keep their documents in the SharePoint portal. I am (as a developer) would rather keep them in TFS (or any other source code repository) closer to the source code. Also in the latest case I would make folders structure in way like "Src", "Doc", "Data" to keep everything more consistent.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Why it is voted to close? What is "subjective" in this question? I am just wondering what is the best practice for documents management...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same issue; my approach has evolved from disliking SharePoint and not posting documentation to a SharePoint portal, to disliking SharePoint and posting documentation anyway.  If your in an environment where it is widely used, then it is very likely no one will see what you create elsewhere.

This is predicated on who your audience, who is using your portal, and who has access to it . . .

If you create a directory structure that is really great: clear, consistent, and reflects low to high levels of detail well, then you provide "The Management," or other colleagues, with access to documentation based on the level they need; relevant to the information they want to extract for their task.

You can also hyper-link to outside documentation if needed from SharePoint. As a side-benefit, you maintain visibility into your work vs. obscurity.

In summary:

1. **Observe  your work-environment** -- maybe your stuck with SharePoint for now.
2. **Define your audience**.
3. **Create awesome directory structures**.
4. **Link to outside documentation** as a solution to certain challenges.
5. **Get some visibility** into your work if you don't already.